# отправка данных вебсокет серверу

Tags: linux, c, websocket

Прохожу handshake без проверки ключа, пока не реализовал. Я немного нашёл информации в инете на русском, но там пример сервера websocket. У меня проблема с построением сообщения.
Я устанавливаю в первый байт вот так значение.

```
void set_fragment ( unsigned char n ) {
  unsigned char byte |= ( n << 7 );
}
```

И опкод

```
void set_opcode ( unsigned char n ) {
        f_byte |= ( n << 0 );
        out[0] = f_byte;
}
```

Далее я делаю так,

```
unsigned int length;

void set_mask_pre ( const char *data, unsigned char sb, const int length_buf ) {
        out[1] = sb;

        unsigned int i = 0, pl = 0;
        int index = 2;
        length = 2;
        for ( ; pl < length_buf + 4; i++, pl++ ) {
                out[ index++ ] = data[i] ^ data[ i % 4 ];
                length++;
        }

}

void set_data ( const char *data ) {
        int length = strlen ( data );
        s_byte |= ( 1 << 7 );
        if ( length < 126 ) {
                s_byte |= length;
                set_mask_pre ( data, s_byte, length );
        } else {
                s_byte |= 126;
        }
}
```

В rfc6455 документе написано что это

```
   Octet i of the transformed data ("transformed-octet-i") is the XOR of
   octet i of the original data ("original-octet-i") with octet at index
   i modulo 4 of the masking key ("masking-key-octet-j"):

     j                   = i MOD 4
     transformed-octet-i = original-octet-i XOR masking-key-octet-j
```

Правильно ли я данные составляю?
Далее я отправляю эти данные на echo сервер, а он мне присылает такие данные. Отправляю я ему слово test.

```
void write_to_websocket ( ) {
        write ( sock_websocket, out, length );
        int ret = read ( sock_websocket, in, SIZE_IN );
        if ( ret == -1 ) {
                perror ( "read" );
                exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        printf ( "ret: %d\n", ret );

        for ( int i = 0; i < ret; i++ ) {
                printf ( "%c", in[i] >= ' ' && in[i] <= '~' ? in[i] : '.' );
        }
        printf ( "\n" );
}
```

Вот ответ.

```
ret: 6
..tesu
```

Answer (score 1):

Я немного поигрался, и echo сервер теперь присылает то что я ему отправляю, я не пробывал на реальном серваке. Вот как я сделал.

```
void set_mask_pre ( const char *data, const int length_buf ) {
        unsigned int i = 0, pl = 0;
        char *s = &out[2];
        int index = 2;
        length = 2;
        char *ss = s;
        for ( ; pl < 4; i++, pl++ ) {
                s [ pl ] = data[ pl ] ^ data[ pl % 4 ];
                length++;
        }
        s += 4;
        pl = 0;
        for ( ; pl < length_buf; i++, pl++ ) {
                s [ pl ] = data[ pl ] ^ ss[ pl % 4 ];
                length++;
        }

}
```